# Subdomain and cookies

Tags: php, .htaccess

When I coded in `.htaccess` and later entered my subdomain name in cpanel every thing was right and was working perfect.(used for url rewriting)

Later  I removed the subdomain name and changed to other subdomain name in cpanel and also changed the code in`.htaccess` respectively..

Initially I was getting the old subdomain name itself (when i click the link)In spite of deleting that subdomain name from cpanel also...
Then By chance when I cleared the entire browsed data,it started working fine with the new subdomain name.(after refreshing too)..

Can any one tell me Why subdomain link is not deleted from browser until we delete the cookies,browsing data ect ?Is there a direct link between domains,subdomains,cookies??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more likely to be cached DNS. Your DNS record for the subdomain will have a TTL (time to live) in seconds which tells how frequently downstream servers should check the origin for any changes. This is normally around 14400 (4 hours) to 86400 (24 hours).

When your machine first queries DNS to get an ip address for subdomain.example.com, it will not check again for the time specified in the TTL. Once this has elapsed, the removed subdomain will no longer resolve to an IP.

It *may* be that clearing your browser cache cleared the dns cache, although I doubt it. It's more likely that this coincided with the TTL elapsing.